# MySQL combine results from UNION of same-scheme tables

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables with the same structure: 'imsc_storage_users' & 'imsc_storage_users_archive'.

My current SELECT/UNION:

```
SELECT `cli`,`ts`,`questions`, `answers`,`correct`,`last`,`minutes` 
FROM  `imsc_storage_users`
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT `cli`,`ts`,`questions`, `answers`,`correct`,`last`,`minutes` 
FROM  `imsc_storage_users_archive`
ORDER BY `correct` DESC,`minutes` ASC
```

I'm getting these results:

```
+--------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+---------+
| cli          | ts                  | questions | answers | correct | last | minutes |
+--------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+---------+
| 111111111111 | 2011-12-22 11:13:57 |        30 |      29 |      14 |   30 | 1305.47 |
| 222222222222 | 2011-12-15 13:39:16 |        26 |      24 |      13 |   24 |   15.67 |
| 333333333333 | 2011-12-15 13:39:39 |        26 |      25 |      11 |   25 |   15.18 |
| 444444444444 | 2011-12-15 13:39:39 |        25 |      21 |      11 |   25 |  280.53 |
| 111111111111 | 2011-12-22 11:13:57 |        25 |      21 |      10 |   25 |  373.87 |
| 555555555555 | 2011-12-19 15:46:15 |        11 |      10 |       5 |   10 |     3.8 |
| 666666666666 | 2011-12-15 13:39:16 |        14 |      10 |       4 |   10 |  321.64 |
| 777777777777 | 2011-12-19 08:34:36 |        15 |      11 |       4 |   13 |  474.66 |
```

Notice that '111111111111' appears twice?

I want it to be combined, **so in the results set I get one row of '111111111111' which combines/sums all fields; 'questions' =>> 55.... etc'**.

What would be the correct SQL?
Performance are NOT of an issue here.

Thank you!

Comment: So, what happens when the same `cli` has different values for `ts`?, how do you combine them?, `MIN`?, `MAX`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT `cli`,max(`ts`) AS ts, sum(`questions`) as questions, sum(`answers`) as answers,sum(`correct`) as correct,sum(`last`) as last,sum(`minutes`) as minutes
FROM (
  SELECT `cli`,`ts`,`questions`, `answers`,`correct`,`last`,`minutes` 
  FROM  `imsc_storage_users`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `cli`,`ts`,`questions`, `answers`,`correct`,`last`,`minutes` 
  FROM  `imsc_storage_users_archive`
) AS baseview
GROUP BY cli
ORDER BY `correct` DESC,`minutes` ASC
```

Comment: Note that UNION DISTINCT will eliminate any exact duplicates between the two tables, even though they should probably be included in the sum values.

Comment: @MarkBannister You, sir, have the eyes of a hawk! Duly corrected.

Comment: Eugen: Not quite ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html ); try UNION ALL.

Comment: Now seeing "The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result." comes as quite a suprise to me - thank goodness I never use UNION in production software ... corrected the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT `cli`,
       `ts`,
       sum(`questions`), 
       sum(`answers`),
       sum(`correct`),
       sum(`last`),
       sum(`minutes`)
FROM (SELECT `cli`,`ts`,`questions`, `answers`,`correct`,`last`,`minutes` 
      FROM  `imsc_storage_users`
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `cli`,`ts`,`questions`, `answers`,`correct`,`last`,`minutes` 
      FROM  `imsc_storage_users_archive`) V
group by `cli`, `ts`
ORDER BY 5 DESC, 7 ASC
```